# Определение url страницы на jQuery

Tags: jquery

Смена url происходит "на ходу" без перезагрузки. Попробовал как видно в коде через нажатие, но определение происходит на текущей странице. Пытался пошаманить с .ready, .load перед нажатием, не работает.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(window.location.hash=='#730')
    {alert('показываем кнопку');}
    else {alert('не показываем кнопку');}

    $(document).on('click','.games_list_tab', function(){
        if(window.location.hash=='#730')
        {alert('показываем кнопку');}
        else {alert('не показываем кнопку');}});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
$(window).bind('hashchange', function() {
    if(window.location.hash == '#730') {
        alert('показываем кнопку');
    } else {
        alert('не показываем кнопку');
    }
});
```